# KDE, per application keyboard shortcut, example: how to customise chrome shortcuts?

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, kde, chrome, kde5

In KDE5 how can we use the same shortcut but achieve different action on per active application basis?

Example i use `F3` in my text editor for `find next` and i want it to refresh the web page when i am using chrome. This question can be assimilated to, how can i customise chrome/chromium shortcuts in KDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KDE have a great advanced shortcuts management system, **the same** global shortcut **can not** be used for different actions right now **BUT** filters like `Active window` or `Existing window` can be applied to the global shortcuts to limit their actions on per application basis.

The **unavailable** KDE feature that would permit a per application action for a **single global shortcut** is a `kwin` only limitation and thus if an application have its own keyboard shortcut implementation, KDE global shortcuts can then be used with filters to achieve the per app action for the same global shortcut.

The filtering feature can as well be useful to **customise the keyboard shortcuts for an application like chromium** or other applications that have built-in shortcuts that can not be edited. Without impacting the other non targeted apps...

The example bellow show **how to use a commonly used shortcut `F3`** (usually used for `find/find-next` action, this is not a global KDE shortcut) to make a `refresh page` action in chromium (without impacting the `F3` search function for other apps):

```
systemsettings5  >  Shortcuts (under workspace)  >  Custom Shortcuts
```

Add a new group *(this is required to be able to filter on per application basis)*:

```
Edit  >  New Group  >  Select the new group  >  Open Condition tab
```

Add the filter condition for an active windows by clicking

```
New  >  Active Window
```

We can then click `New...` then use `browser` as a value for the window role (if we are targeting all the browsers)

Now that our group is setup, we need to add a new global shortcut in it, we will be simulating `F5` (refresh action) with the button `F3`.

```
Select the new group  >  Edit  >  New  >  Global shortcut  >  Send keyboard input
```

An finally on the trigger tab we would assign `F3` and on the action we would write `F5`... The captures bellow demonstrate the whole process.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]